# XSLT - Find attribute value using regular expression and string length

Tags: xml, xslt

Input XML is like,

```
<link idref="c001_r1" target="page">1</link>
<link idref="r164">2004</link>
<link idref="ref1">Austen et al. 1975</link>
```

Output should be,

```
<link idref="c001_r1" target="literature"><sup>1</sup></link>
<link idref="r164" target="literature">2004</link>
<link idref="ref1" target="literature">Austen et al. 1975</link>
```

We wrote xslt like below.

```
 <xsl:template match="link">
    <xsl:choose>            
         <xsl:when test="starts-with(@idref, 'r') and string-length(.) = 4">
             <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="target">
                <xsl:value-of select="'literature'" />
            </xsl:attribute>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
             </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with(@idref, 'ref') and string-length(.) > 4">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="target">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'literature'" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(@idref, '(.+)_r')">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="target">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'literature'" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <sup>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></sup>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="starts-with(@idref, 'ref') and string-length(.) < 3">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="target">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'literature'" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <sup>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </sup>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/> 
                <xsl:attribute name="target"><xsl:text>page</xsl:text>                        
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>        
</xsl:template>
```

While using above xslt, 3rd and 4th conditions are not working. We need to add attribute based on attribute value and string length. We are unable to mention less than(<) sign, to calculate sting length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than saying "it is not working" you should have really mentioned any error you are getting. For the `<` sign, you are probably getting an error along the lines of "*The value of attribute "test" associated with an element type "xsl:when" must not contain the '<' character.*"

The syntax of your `xsl:when` should be this

```
<xsl:when test="starts-with(@idref, 'ref') and string-length(.) &lt; 3">
```

Or better still, this, if you are using XSLT 2.0 or above

```
<xsl:when test="starts-with(@idref, 'ref') and string-length(.) lt 3">
```

For the other condition, you are using `contains`, but that does not support regular expressions. It simply checks if one string is a substring of another. You need to use `matches` here

```
<xsl:when test="matches(@idref, '.+_r.+')">
```

This requires XSLT 2.0 or above though.

Note that you have a lot of repeated code. Try simplifying it to this, for example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="link">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
           <xsl:if test="(starts-with(@idref, 'r') and string-length(.) = 4)
                         or (starts-with(@idref, 'ref') and string-length(.) > 4)
                         or (matches(@idref, '.+_r.+'))
                         or (starts-with(@idref, 'ref') and string-length(.) lt 3)">
                <xsl:attribute name="target" select="'literature'" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
         </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanku for your valuable response with more clarification. It's really very helpful.